# Simple stream image contents by Gin, Golang

Tags: go, streaming, go-gin

I am new to golang and trying to create an API that returns consecutive images stored in the local folder using Gin.
My current implementation is the following;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
var imagePaths = []string{"static/1.png", "static/2.png", "static/3.png", "static/4.png"}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/stream", func(c *gin.Context) {
        chanStream := make(chan []byte)
        go func() {
            defer close(chanStream)
            var i = 0
            for {
                file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(imagePaths[i])
                chanStream <- file
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
                if i == 3 {
                    i = -1
                }
                i++
            }
        }()

        c.Stream(func(w io.Writer) bool {
            if msg, ok := <-chanStream; ok {
                w.Write(msg)
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
    })

    router.Run("localhost:8080")
}
```

What I am trying to do is to read each image stored in under static folder every 500ms and return the images one by one every 500ms as a response. This code returns the first image but not return the next image. When I print the image length above the w.Write(msg), it print the image length meaning that the image byte stream is properly given to the msg under the c.Stream method.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are only writing the first file contents to the output. Use this instead:

```
c.Stream(func(w io.Writer) bool {
            for msg:=range chanStream {
                w.Write(msg)
            }
            return false
        })
```

But, the way your program is written, this will create an infinite stream, because the goroutine writing to the `chanStream` never ends.

Also, there is no indication to the reader that you are returning multiple files. For a client, this will look like a continuous stream with some random delays in between.